# Is there any easy way to analyse transparent png image with cv2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to load a transparent image (just without background) with CV2 but when I try to show the image I get a black background. Is there any possible (and easy) way to load transparent PNG image?
The input:

[image: The result I get]
The result:
[image: The result I get]

This is the result I get:
Even if i'm trying
this code:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('test',im)
```

I get the result with black background

Comment: can you post the snippet of code you are using to load & display the image.

Comment: Kindly show the **Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example** of code required for Stack Overflow questions, and since your question is about image processing, also show your original input image at least. Thank you.

Comment: @anekix
To load:
source_image = cv2.imread('filename.png')
To Display:
cv2.imshow('window_name', source_image)

Comment: @beaker
I'm trying to analyse colors at image but i've got black as result because of background...

Comment: Do you have a transparent monitor? Perhaps it's just the black shining through the transparent region? A monitor cannot show transparent colors. If you don't specify a background explicitly, perhaps black is just the default.

Comment: @ThomasWeller guess i dont, but i want to analyse colors (even without displaying) on the image and still get black as a resoult

Comment: Kindly put code in your question rather than in the comments where it is unformatted and difficult to read. The answer to your question is that you need to add a second parameter to `cv2.imread()`.

Comment: @beaker i have tried this and i only get that "name 'cvLoadImage' is not defined"

Comment: opencv doesn't support transparent rendering, even if an alpha channel is present. To load the image WITH its alpha channel you need a special flag for imread, otherwise it will always read as 3 channel (even if the image is only grayscale). After reading with given allga channel, you can accesd the chsnnel, read it, use transparency and save a png with teansparency

Comment: cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1, but keep in mind, that rendering (imshow) will still not use transparency at all.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are loading has four channels. Check the array size. Channel 4 is the alpha channel and you can save the image back accordingly with an alpha channel. You can also generate a mask from the alpha channel (in OpenCV masks are binary with values 0, and 255, respectively).

Most of OpenCV operations work on 4-channel images, but they do not treat the alpha channel special or derive any information from it.

Answer (score 1):

cv.loadImage() is for MultiCameraCalibration. Use cv.imread() for single images. To get transparency, you must use the flag of cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV. Note that with the cv.imshow you will not see transparency. It will be black. To do further analysis, you should extract the alpha channel as a mask and use that for whatever you want to do to limit the processing to the shoe and not the background around it.

```
import cv2

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('shoe.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# get mask from alpha channel
mask = img[:,:,3]

# view images
# NOTE: imshow does not show transparency. It will be black there.
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Saving the image does contain transparency as can be seen when viewed with some external viewer.
cv2.imwrite('shoe_copy.png', img)
```

Comment: What if I want to see somehow that transparency as not black? is there a way to do that?

Comment: OpenCV display does not show transparency. It shows as black only unless you make the image not black in those places by using the mask to colorize it and turn transparency off.